# file size limitation for upload in django

Tags: django, file, input, request, size

I want to limit the size of uploaded files on the site and I want not to work with forms and handle myself with html and input tags. What should I do to get the file from the input type file? I made request.POST but it did not access the file. Can you guide me?

```
<input type="file" class="shadow-sm form-control" onchange="imageLimition(event)" id="image" name="image" required>

def register(request):
    file = request.POST.get('image').size 
    validate_file_size(file)

def validate_file_size (value):
    filesize = value.size
    print(filesize)
    if filesize > 512*1024 :
        raise ValidationError("error ")
    else : 
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

use `request.FILES.get('image')` and make sure that you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```